# Error "Script function not found: doGet" while there is no doGet function but doPost function

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am having issue with the app script.
I have deployed below script with access to anyone however when ran it keeps giving error of "Script function not found: doGet"

what is it that I am doing wrong. All the steps in deployment is correct.

i want to get list email ids & link into google sheet of the user that clicks on the link
URL of the script
[https://script.google.com/macros/s/[script-id]/exec](https://script.google.com/macros/s/%5Bscript-id%5D/exec)

URL of the link

[http://script.google.com/macros/s/[script-id]/exec?to=abc.def@gmail.com&link=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nd3DV_heK2Q](http://script.google.com/macros/s/%5Bscript-id%5D/exec?to=abc.def@gmail.com&link=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nd3DV_heK2Q)

Script is as follows

```
function doPost(e) {
  try {
    // Store a reference for the tracking spreadsheet
    var trackingSpSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById([Sheet ID]);
    // Store a reference for the Logs sheet
    var outputSheet = trackingSpSheet.getSheetByName([Sheet Name]);
    // Get the number of the last row in the Logs sheet with no content
    var lastRow = outputSheet.getLastRow() + 1;

    // Check if the 'elink' parameter is present to determine if it's a link click
    if (typeof e !== 'undefined') {
      // Log link click
      var clickData = [new Date(), e.parameter.to, e.parameter.link];
      outputSheet.getRange(lastRow, 1, 1, clickData.length).setValues([clickData]);
      //Logger.log("Link Click Logged:", clickData);
      //console.log("Link Click Logged:", clickData);
    } else {
      // Log email open
      var openData = [new Date(), e.parameter.to];
      outputSheet.getRange(lastRow, 1, 1, openData.length).setValues([openData]);
      //console.log("Email Open Logged:", openData);
      //Logger.log("Email Open Logged:", openData);
    }

    // Return a string version of e to comply with the web app requirement
    return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(e));
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error in doPost:", error.message);
    return ContentService.createTextOutput("Error: " + error.message);
  }
}
```

Comment: - [Welcome to StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: Please show the calling script.

Answer (score 0):

When a user clicks, the browser makes a `GET` request. Therefore, you need `doGet()` function.

Also,

- Make sure the deployment is at a newest version. If there isn't one, you have  to create a new version at the time of deployment.
- Note that the url differs from  each deployment.  Make sure to test the latest url.